# Devise NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a small problem that I cant track down. Basically I have my application controller and in my application controller I have a method:

```
def getCategories
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Nothing special I have a sidebar partial view that I load in to my main layout. This partial is loaded by almost all controllers/actions with few exceptions so to avoid always declaring this method i simply have a before_filter to invoke this method so that `@categories` are automatically included in all controllers.

The problem now is when I attempt to login using devise sign in view it tries to redirect me to `root` however for some reason the `@categories` are not included and in turn throw this exception:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#create
```

Which is confusing because according to devise documentation if you set `root :to => 'home#index'` as in my case after processing user login user should be redirected to root which points to home controller which should due to `before_filter` include the `@categoires` variable.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try adding a new controller "Registrations" and add your method:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

   def getCategories
      @categories = Category.all
   end

end
```

then Modify config/routes.rb to use the new controller

Modify your devise_for line in routes.rb to look like the below.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

replace `root :to => 'home#index'` with

```
  devise_scope :user do
    match "/", to: "devise/registrations#new", via: 'get'
  end
```